# In iPhone, how to store audio file picked from media picker to some directory?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mpmediapickercontroller

How can I write an audio file picked from `mediaPicker` into some particular folder? We are currently writing image to file path with this method:

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

Is it possible for to do the same kind of thing with an audio file?

Thanks.

Comment: hey you can try this tutorial:-http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/07/19/from-iphone-media-library-to-pcm-samples-in-dozens-of-confounding-potentially-lossy-steps/

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

is a method of the `NSData` class, so, once you have fetched your audio from the media picker, you should totally be able to write it to a file that way.

---

Note: You might have to convert the audio picked to NSData first

Cheers

Comment: Keep in mind, this isn't going to be a .mp3 - It's data that you can decode as normal.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to store it as media(Audio) file only so I can play it directly

Comment: @Aurum Aquila, Can You suggest something that can fulfil my requirement

Comment: @Prerak Sorry, I have 0 experience with writing/reading media files on the iPhone.

Comment: But how to convert the audio file fetched from iPod Library into NSData? Can you please explain that in more detailed manner?